# What medical supplies to take for a small child for a stay in a remote village?

Tags: health, children, remote-locations

During our upcoming holiday, we'll be spending about a month in a remote village, about 3 hours drive from the nearest city, probably about 2 hours drive from the nearest pharmacy. After heavy rains, the road becomes unusable and it may be a couple of days before we'd be able to get to a pharmacy.

As we'll be going with our 11-month old twins, I want to cover their needs first, medical supplies-wise.  I have the following list:

- Calpol (children paracetamol)
- Nurofen (children ibuprofen)
- Salin nasal spray
- Teething gel
- Children antihistamine
- Nappy rash cream
- Hydrogen peroxide
- Thermometer

What other medicine should I take?

**Edit:** we'll be in the Caucasian mountains, in Georgia (*not* the GA, USA).  There are no African bees, bears, volcanoes or malaria, but there are regular mosquitoes and bees, lots of sun and a very fast mountain stream/river and, at the same time, very cold nights.

Comment: It would help folks answer your question if they knew where you are going.

Comment: What are your expected hazards? Malaria? Bears? Africanized bees? Cholera? Volcanoes?

Comment: Good point, actually.  There are no bears, cholera or volcanoes around, nor African bees.  We'll be in Georgia, in the Caucasian mountains.  There are some wolves, but they don't come into the village. So I'm mostly concerned with some basic stuff that can happen anywhere.

Comment: No bears? I wouldn't be so sure about this one...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You seem to forget one aspect: injuries. As far as I know, those are almost as common as anything else with children. So as a minimum I'd definitely take:

- some plasters, bandages and gauze pads
- antiseptic spray or cream for wounds, maybe antiseptic wipes to clean out wounds
- cream for sprains or muscle ache and to treat sunburns
- tweezers to get out splinters or ticks

Of course the last two will depend on what activities do you do and where you live. But I urge you not to forget about the first aid supplies for injuries. You will most certainly be fine with a child in pain who has to wait for 2 days to get pain medication, but a wound which you don't have the means to treat correctly can become dangerous quite quickly.

Comment: Thanks!  I didn't list those as I take injury-type first aid with me on every trip, with children or otherwise.  Naturally, I'll have a good supply of those, as well as a descent supply of facial tissues.

Answer (score 1):

On top of all the other things mentioned I would really suggest having an oral **antibiotic**. These are sold as powder in a bottle, you get water separately and then you mix it together just before first use. After it is mixed you need to keep in refrigerated, but you can carry it around in the powder form before mixing. Obviously you only want to use it if other things don't work (e.g. ibuprofen and paracetamol don't get the temperature down).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not sure how I'd manage to get the antibiotic without a prescription though, especially for a child.

Comment: Until a few months ago, antibiotics were available OTC in Georgia.  Can't imagine it would it be particularly hard to get them now either; if all else, get a prescription from a doctor who understands your situation.  http://www.euro.who.int/en/countries/georgia/news/news/2013/12/marking-european-antibiotic-awareness-day-in-georgia